# If I learn Gtk3 expert level with C, can I learn PyGtk3 expert level?

Tags: gtk3

I know this question can be nonsense. but anything for learning gtk3 with C (tutorials on the net, books, everything in the world) are too many than anything for learning pygtk3, java gtk3, ... so I can learn gtk3 expert level with C. if I do this, can I learn pygtk expert level.

Comment: Yes, as long as you practice in Python as well.

Comment: @ptomato, Thanks.